# Qt && firebase C++ SDK linking issues on iOS

Tags: c++, xcode, qt, firebase, linker-errors

I have following build env:

- host: OSX 10.12 Sierra
- XCode 9.2
- Qt 5.10.1 for iOS
- QtCreator 4.7.0
- firebase 5.2

and try to build my application from QtCreator for iOS with the firebase support, but it fails with following linking errors:

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRMessaging", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in firebase_messaging(messaging_231c52c311096cfce13e67fa91eb9ac5.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRApp", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in firebase(app_ios_814e1620d4f88024cea4bade26623a67.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIROptions", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in firebase(app_ios_814e1620d4f88024cea4bade26623a67.o) ld: symbol(s) not
>   found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with
>   exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have simplified my project to following code:

== main.cpp ==

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include <firebase/app.h>
#include <firebase/messaging.h>
#include <firebase/util.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    ::firebase::App *fapp = ::firebase::App::Create();
    Q_UNUSED(fapp);
    return a.exec();
}
```

and a project file is:

```
QT -= gui
CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

# Check for GOOGLE_FIREBASE_SDK environment variable.
ENV_GOOGLE_FIREBASE_SDK = $$(GOOGLE_FIREBASE_SDK)
# Or define GOOGLE_FIREBASE_SDK path here.
GOOGLE_FIREBASE_SDK =

isEmpty(ENV_GOOGLE_FIREBASE_SDK) {
    isEmpty(GOOGLE_FIREBASE_SDK) {
        message("GOOGLE_FIREBASE_SDK" environment variable not detected!)
    }
}

INCLUDEPATH += $$(GOOGLE_FIREBASE_SDK)
INCLUDEPATH += $$(GOOGLE_FIREBASE_SDK)/include

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

FCM_LIBS_PATH = $$(GOOGLE_FIREBASE_SDK)/frameworks/ios/universal
message("FCM_LIBS_PATH = $$FCM_LIBS_PATH")

LIBS += -F$$FCM_LIBS_PATH \
   -framework firebase_messaging \
   -framework firebase \
   -framework Foundation \
   -framework UserNotifications \
   -framework UIKit \
   -framework CoreGraphics
```

The firebase SDK contains different frameworks directories for different architectures :

- ~/firebase_cpp_sdk/frameworks/ios/universal
- ~/firebase_cpp_sdk/frameworks/ios/amd64
- ~/firebase_cpp_sdk/frameworks/ios/i386
- ~/firebase_cpp_sdk/frameworks/ios/x86_64
- ~/firebase_cpp_sdk/frameworks/ios/armv7

As I see that error related to 'arm64' architecture, so, I have changed the project file LIBS to use 'arm64' instead of 'universal', but this does not help.

Also I tried to build the project from the XCode, using qmake's generated xcode.project file, but there are same error.

I looked on stackoverflow a similar issues, but that workarounds does not help:

- I tried to remove the /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData directory.
- I tried to play with the XCode options "Build Settings -> Build Active Architecture Only -> yes|no"

I looked a code from the following projects:

- qtcloudmessaging: https://github.com/qt/qtcloudmessaging
- QtFirebase: https://github.com/Larpon/QtFirebase

But I don't understand why this linker error happens.. Maybe is it a qmake bug?

Comment: Did you manage to link? We have a similar issue opened at Firebase GitHub: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-cpp-sdk/issues/19

Comment: @DanielNicoletti I don't see the native FirebaseIOS libs, which the SDK depends on? I had to manually build and copy the .a static library files from a dummy Xcode project (as QMake doesn't support Cocoapods... :/), and add them to the linker like `LIBS += -L$$FIREBASE_IOS_LIBDIR -ObjC -lFirebaseAuth -lFirebaseCore -lFirebaseDatabase -lFirebaseInstanceID -lFirebaseStorage  -lGTMSessionFetcher -lGoogleToolboxForMac -lGoogleUtilities -lleveldb-library -lnanopb -lsqlite3 -framework GameKit -framework SafariServices -framework SystemConfiguration`. Note the "-ObjC", it was crucial.

Comment: Thinking about it, I think the -ObjC only came into play at runtime, without it the app or storage initialization resulted in a failure

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld, I have an empty project XCode project, I've added the firebase cocoaPods, but I have no clue how I can manually build .a static libraries from there.    Do you remember how you did that?

Answer (score 2):

The error means the project lacks Firebase pod.

`firebase_cpp_sdk` alone is not enough, in addition, it requires Firebase Core library.

In order add Firebase lib, you should migrate to use cocoapods.

In the project's source root, run
`pod init`
a new file `Podfile` would be then generated.

Open the file, add the following line to the target
`pod 'Firebase/Analytics'`
and save the file.

After running
`pod update`
successfully, open the `.xcworkspace` and build as usual.